# Identification of spaceship's Habitation Modules and Life Support Modules

Tags: freeciv

The [documentation](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Buildings) has this to say about Space Modules:

> Space Modules are the most expensive parts of spaceships. There are three different types of Space Module:
>
> - Habitation Module: provides living space for 10,000 people.
> - Life Support Module: provides food and water for the population of one Habitation Module.
> - Solar Panels: provides the energy needed for any two of the other Modules.
>
> You can build up to 4 Space Modules of each kind.

It's easy to identify a Solar Panel Module:
[image: Freeciv spaceship solar panel module]

But what about the Habitation Module and Life Support Module?

[image: Freeciv spaceship module]
[image: Freeciv spaceship module]

Which is which? Is the one with four circles a Habitation Module or a Life Support Module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaceship sprites come from a sprite sheet ([data/misc/space.png](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/space.png)):

[image: Freeciv spaceship sprite sheet]

Excerpt from this sprite sheet's spec file ([data/misc/space.spec](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/space.spec)):

```
tiles = { "row", "column", "tag"

  0,  0, "spaceship.solar_panels"
  0,  1, "spaceship.life_support"
  0,  2, "spaceship.habitation"
  0,  3, "spaceship.structural"
  0,  4, "spaceship.fuel"
  0,  5, "spaceship.propulsion"
  0,  6, "spaceship.exhaust"
}
```

Therefore:

[image: Freeciv spaceship's life support module] is the life support module.

[image: Freeciv spaceship's habitation module] is the habitation module.